Find impulse response to this first order difference linear equation
Given this first order linear system, with a single input (m=1) and a single output (p=1);
$y(k) +a_1 y(k-1) = b_0u(k)+b_1u(k-1)$
I don't know how to demonstrate that the impulse response is
$ with \space h(0)=b_0 ,\space  h(j)=(b_1 -a_1b_0)(-a_1)^{j-1}, j>0$

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.
